# Displaying a prioryityQueue in an android list view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, priority-queue

I have a priority queue that I want to display to the user like a list view is displayed. Do I need to create a custom adapter? If so which adapter class should I extend? Thank you very much.

Here is some of my code. playlist used to be a list but I now want it to be a priorityQueue. Track adapter is just an extension of ArrayAdapter.

`PriorityQueue<VotableTrack> playlist = mServerService.getPlaylist();
     mAdapter = new TrackAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.id.text1, playlist);
     mServerService.setPlaylistArrayAdapter(mAdapter);
     mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

`

Comment: you already have a data, you just need to show it. you can use anyhting

Comment: That is a good point. I'd like to just to pass my PriorityQueue to my current  ArrayAdapter but obviously I get an error. I'll add some code to my question. Thank you for the response.

Comment: what kind of data are you showing, is it string or number

Comment: tried `Collection.toArray()` when passing to `ArrayAdapter` ?

Comment: @pskink .Yes that worked. Thank you :)

Comment: @pskink The only problem is that if the priority queues order changes the list view doesn't.

Comment: @patrick_corrigan so you need to extend `BaseAdapter` ...